# How to do while loop in ARMSim with 2 conditions?

Tags: assembly, while-loop, arm

I"m trying to do an insert sort in arm assembly but I have no idea how to do a while loop with 2 conditions? I got this psuedocode for the algorithm here from wikipedia but I am having trouble translating the while loop to ARM instructions because there are 2 condtions.

```
for i = 1 to length(A)
x = A[i]
j = i - 1
while j >= 0 and A[j] > x
    A[j+1] = A[j]
    j = j - 1
end while
A[j+1] = x
end for
```

Here is my attempt at translating the code to ARM assembly instructions, the array is holding 20 integers:

```
MOV R7, #0                             ;intialize index
ForLoop:
CMP R7, #20                            ;check if end of array
BEQ EndFor                        ;exit for loop if done
LDR R1, =array                         ;Load array address
MOV R2, R7, LSL #2                     ;multiply array index r7 by 4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2                         ;Set R2 to element address
LDR R1, [R2]                           ;R1 = A[R7]

MOV R8, R1                             ;R8 = R1

SUB R9, R7, #1                         ;R9 = R7 - 1

LDR R1, =array                         ;Load array address
MOV R2, R9, LSL #2                     ;multiply array index r9 by 4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2                         ;Set R2 to element address
LDR R3, [R2]                           ;r3 = A[r9]

WhileLoop:  
CMP R9, #0                             ;while >= 0
BEQ Endwhile
CMP R3, R8                         ;while R3> R8
BEQ Endwhile

LDR R1, =array                         ;Load array address
MOV R2, R9, LSL #2                     ;multiply array index r9 by 4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2                         ;Set R2 to element address
LDR R3, [R2]                           ;r3 = A[r9]

ADD R9, R9, #1                         ;R9 = R9 + 1
LDR R1, =array                         ;Load array address
MOV R2, R9, LSL #2                     ;multiply array index by 4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2                         ;Set R2 to element address
STR R3, [R2]                           ;A[R9] = R3

SUB R9, R9, #1                    ;R9 = R9 - 1

B WhileLoop

Endwhile: 
ADD R9, R9, #1                         ;R9 = R9 + 1
LDR R1, =array                         ;Load array address
MOV R2, R9, LSL #2                     ;multiply array index by 4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2                         ;Set R2 to element address
STR R8, [R2]                           ;A[R9] = R8
ADD R7, R7, #1                         ;increment index
B ForLoop
EndFor:
```

When I run the program, my code runs in an infinite loop in while loop. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're doing `R9 = R9 + 1` and `R9 = R9 - 1` in the loop so `j` is never reaching 0. I think you should use another variable to store `j+1`

Comment: Even if you fix the error that jack3694078 pointed out, the way you check `A[j] > x` still looks incorrect. For every iteration except the first you appear to be using `A[j]` from the previous iteration in the check, but since `j` is supposed to be decremented at the end of each iteration that makes `A[j]` from the previous iteration `A[j+1]` for _this_ iteration.

Comment: Why do you have `eq` condition codes, i.e. `==`, for tests which are apparently supposed to be `>=` and `>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
while j >= 0 and A[j] > x
    A[j+1] = A[j]
    j = j -1
```

would be

```
while 1
   if (j<0) break;
   if (a[j] <= x) break;
    A[j+1] = A[j]
    j = j -1
```

your code is checking for j==0 and A[j]==0 instead

also INSIDE your loop, you're increasing R9 to read A[j+1], but not restoring it
instead of manually calculating the "+1" you could do an offset'ed `LDR R3, [R2, #4]` which would do the "+1" for you

Answer (score 0):

You question says you have difficulty with this line; `while j >= 0 and A[j] > x`.  The way a compiler implement **OR** and **AND** is as follows,

```
AND_CASE:
 tst cond1
 bxx  end_loop  ; false 1st condition
 tst cond2
 bxx  end_loop  ; false 2nd condition
 ; true code
 b AND_CASE
end_loop:

OR_CASE:
 tst cond1
 bxx true   ; short circuit (doesn't do 2nd statement)
 tst cond2
 bxx end_loop ; false 2nd condition
true:
 ; true code
 b OR_CASE
end_loop:
```

For your case you check the index and then use it.

```
AND_CASE:
 tst reg_j     ; testing index 'j'
 bmi end_loop  ; false
 ; r0 represents some free scratch register...
 ldr r0, [reg_a, reg_j, LSL #2]  ; get the memory
 cmp r0,reg_x            ; compare vs key
 blt end_loop  ; false
 ; true code
 b AND_CASE
end_loop:
```

Verify that the condition are appropriate for your signed-ness.  The important point is that the compiler with test one condition at a time and then do a branch depending on whether it is **OR** or **AND**; the conditions are just inverted for the branch.  Assembler programmers must usually do the same thing as a compiler.  Every thing is the same for `if`, `for`, etc statements and their conditions.

You have the basic structure correct, but I think that you need to move the `ldr` to the 'test block' and not include it else where; ie the 2nd condition test.  As well, you need to get your signs and conditions correct.  I would prefer not to give this information as it is wrote memorization and a good exercise for learning.

Comment: ARM support many indexing modes so you don't need to manually calculate the `A[j]` address in a scratch register.  Also, it is very important to keep track of registers and not use one register for the different things!  It is good to 'name' the registers if your assembler supports it or at least keep comments saying what a register is being used for.